# How to mark Jenkins' job stage as skipped, for scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I mark a stage as skipped when using **scripted pipeline**. 
I have no problem skipping a stage in declarative pipeline. I just set

```
when {
  expression {<some boolean expression>}

}
```

And if the expression is evaluate to false that stage is skipped.
[image]

The problem is that if you try to do this with **scrippted pipeline** you get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'when' found among steps
```

error message. This is because the DSL of declarative pipeline is not the same as **scripted pipeline** 
  So, how can it be done?

Comment: Did you manage to get solution to this ?

Answer (score 35):

Solving this issue takes a little bit of hacking... (don't worry, nothing fancy)

The way to do this is by using Jenkins' module [that can be found here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/master/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/Utils.groovy).

So to mark a stage as skipped you need to call static method ***markStageSkippedForConditional*** passing the name of the stage you are skipping.

Lets say you have a stage named "mystage". and you want to skip it and **mark** it as "skipped".
Your code should look something like:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

node() {
  stage('a'){
    echo 'stage 1'
  }
  stage('mystage'){
    if(true){
       echo 'skipping stage...'
       Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional('mystage')
    }else{
      echo 'This stage may be skipped'

    }
  }
  stage('b'){
    echo 'stage 2'
  }
}
```

If you're using a version of Jenkins older than [mid 2019](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/commit/587d73c66f11d817eb01aca56eeb3daf15d70508), you must uncheck `Use Groovy Sandbox` checkbox, since the Utils method was not yet whitelisted for external use.

Comment: ..or you can allow usage of this method in global configuration of Jenkins

Comment: No need to uncheck `Use Groovy Sandbox` and explicitly allow usage.
This Method is now whitelisted.
Tested with  Jenkins 2.277.2

Comment: if it's more convenient to you, instead of import, you can specify the whole library + the method together: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional('stage name')`

Answer (score 17):

You can find an implementation (in the form of a shared pipeline step) in [comquent/imperative-when](https://github.com/comquent/imperative-when/blob/master/vars/when.groovy) on GitHub.

This allows to access the method `Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional` that you found yourself in a nice way, like the following:

```java
stage('Zero') {
    when(BRANCH_NAME != 'master') {
        echo 'Performing steps of stage Zero'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
As I stated the when block is not available under scripted pipeline. It only available under declarative pipeline.

Comment: @SagiForbes He uses an implementation for scripted pipelines.

Comment: Using when in scripted pipeline will throw NoSuchMethodError. (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'when' found). The shared library approach may help: https://comquent.de/en/skipped-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/

Answer (score -1):

In **declarative pipeline** you can use:

```
stage('deploy') {
        when {  <some boolean expression> }
......
}
```

In **Scripted pipeline** you can use:

```
if(<some boolean expression>) {
stage('deploy') {
......
   }
}
```

both above works fine. i tested

Comment: The scripted option you mentioned removes the visualization of all previous job runs and doesn't mark the step as skipped.